# How to create an Underconstruction message and Setting for a Wordpress website without using plugin

Tags: static-website, notices

I am building up a website for C Programming Tutorial www.programminginc.net . Now I am using a plugin to show my site under construction. What is the code used to create a website under construction setup?

Comment: If either of these answers worked for you, please take a moment to check it as accepted so the question can be closed and helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way to do it is to create a file named `.maintenance` at the root of the site-- same directory as `license.txt`-- and add a bit of PHP:

```
<?php

die();
```

Of course, you can create whatever markup and messages you'd like before the `die();`, but there is very little WordPress available since [it fires very early](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-settings.php#L48) in the `wp-settings.php` file.

If you want to see how to add and remove the file automatically, [look at how the core does it](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/includes/update-core.php#L593).

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options:

1. Create a static HTML "Coming Soon" page and redirect outside requests to your domain to that page. This will let you continue to work on your site (hopefully you're developing locally and pushing changes to your live site) without your visitors loading up the WordPress side.
2. Create a basic WordPress theme with your "Coming Soon" page as `index.php` and set the theme as default. You can use a plugin like [Theme Test Drive](http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-test-drive/) to test out the one you're developing while your visitors see the "Coming Soon" theme.